# How to prevent unwanted scaling of textures in world space

Tags: unity

I allow players to select buildings of different sizes in my game, in the image below is a building that is 30x30 units and one that is 10x10 units.

To indicate that the building is selected, I added a child called `Selection indicator`, this child is simply a texture dragged into the scene, which creates a plane. I activate/deactivate this on select/deselect.

So far so good, but as you can see in the image, in order to match the different sizes, I need to scale the `Selection indicator`, which distorts its edges. Simply using sprite editor here does not seem to change anything since it's in world space.

How could I approach this in a way that the frame for my `Selection indicator` does not stretch like in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a plane, use the [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) component. The reason is that the sprite renderer allows you to use [9-sliced images](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html), like you might know them from the UI system.

First, go to the sprite renderer and set "Draw Mode: Sliced".

Then go to the import settings of the texture you use to represent the select indicator, set "Texture Mode: Sprite (2D and UI)", "Sprite Type: Single" and "Mesh Type: Full Rect". Then click on "Sprite Editor" and and enter the  width in pixels for the left, right, top and bottom border like this:

[image: 9-sliced image]

If you want to change the size of the indicator game object, do **not** use `transform.scale`, because that will also enlarge the edges and corners. Use the [SpriteRenderer.size](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-size.html) property instead. It will resize the center without changing the width of the border.